# How to set TCP NODELAY for db connections on a spring boot application

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data

I have a java web application built on spring boot and spring data using Hikari pool,  deployed in azure Kubernetes cluster, connecting to azure postgres database. To solve a performance issue the Azure team has advised to set TCP NODELAY for this application. Can you please advise how to configure this for the spring application

Comment: Set the [`tcpNoDelay`](https://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/head/connect.html#connection-parameters) connection parameter on the PostgreSQL JDBC driver.

Answer (score 2):

After PostgreSQL JDBC Driver 42.3.2 version you can use TCP_NODELAY option by adding 'tcpNoDelay=true' at the end of the JDBC URL like `jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/postgres?tcpNoDelay=true`
But before this version TCP_NODELAY does not supported.

Updating PostgreSQL JDBC Driver for Spring Boot
for Maven project you can set the PostgreSQL Driver version like

```
<properties>
   <postgresql.version>42.3.2</postgresql.version>
</properties>
```

in pom.xml.

PostgreSQL JDBC Driver Updates;

The issue link : https://github.com/pgjdbc/pgjdbc/issues/2324

The commit link : https://github.com/pgjdbc/pgjdbc/commit/2a8ecbe2321ed92bc7051d3415a0484a5464346b#diff-af76c66c8a01becfcbfe739ba0cc2e4333e7d27865cb67cbb63db2e6f534801a